# How to build a 32 bit linux module remotely from visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ubuntu, cmake, cross-platform

I have been trying to create a cross-platform project.
Both 32 bit and 64 bit binaries (dlls) need to be built.
I am using Visual Studio and selecting x86-Release or x64-Release solves the problem for windows.

But for linux it is always building 64 bit binaries.

After searching, i found that g++ multilib needs to be installed and -m32 flag needs to be passed to both the compiler and linker.
I found that

```
set_target_properties(PROJECT_NAME PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")
```

will solve the problem.

So to build a 32 bit linux binary (MODULE with .so ending), i added the above code.

I also have this code beneath the above code

```
if(WIN32)
    if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
        message("WIN32 x64")
    else()
        message("WIN32 x32")
    endif()
else(WIN32)
    if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
        message("LINUX x64")
    else()
        message("LINUX x32")
    endif()
endif(WIN32)
```

However, it outputs

```
1> [CMake] LINUX x64
```

So it is still building 32 bit build.

I have both g++ and g++ multilib installed, but not sure visual studio is calling which one. could that be the problem?

Comment: You set the `-m32` flags for a specific target. The [`CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P.html) variable is set by a generic test-build. You need to add `-m32` to the general options before the C or C++ compiler is checked and this information is collected.

Comment: I understand but not know how. btw i found that the build it is building when m32 flag is set is actually 32 bit, even though it shows me message "Linux x64" as posted in question. This is because on running command ```objdump -f module.so | grep ^architecture``` gives 
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000150:

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, it was found that CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P is not able to detect if m32 flag is passed.
So i modified the code like this

```
if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    set(OUTPUT_BITNESS 64)
else()
    set(OUTPUT_BITNESS 32)
endif()
if(FORCE_32)
    set_target_properties(PROJECT_NAME PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")
    set(OUTPUT_BITNESS 32)
endif()

if(WIN32)
    if(OUTPUT_BITNESS EQUAL 64)
        message("WIN32 x64")
    else()
        message("WIN32 x32")
    endif()
else(WIN32)
    if(OUTPUT_BITNESS EQUAL 64)
        message("LINUX x64")
    else()
        message("LINUX x32")
    endif()
endif(WIN32
```

So to compile for 32 bit, FORCE_32 variable must be set to 1.