# How to create a cmake variable

Tags: visual-studio, ubuntu, cmake, g++, 32bit-64bit

I just asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71676871/how-to-build-a-32-bit-linux-module-remotely-from-visual-studio)

That problem is solved by myself. All i want is to create two project configurations x86-Linux and x64-Linux in Visual studio CMake Project.

I have both WSL and remote linux.

See, in the link, i have a variable `FORCE_32`. If it is set to 1, i hope cmake will proceed to build the correct binaries. But the problem is how to set this variable via "Manage Configurations" or "CMakeSettings.json". I tried

```
 "variables": [
        {
          "name": "FORCE_32",
          "value": "1",
          "type": "INTEGER"
        }
      ]
```

in CMakeSettings.json and to which i got this warning in Visual Studio

```
manually-specified variables were not used by the project visual studio FORCE_32

Linux -x64
```

I do not know how to proceed. All i am trying to do is a way so that 32 or 64 bit builds can be built any time **without editing CMakeLists.txt each time**

Answer (score 0):

In CMakeSettings.json modify

```
"cmakeCommandArgs": "-DFORCE_32:INTEGER=1",
```